# Facebook share doesn't show the correct information

Tags: html, share, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I recently added a share button on all of the artwork on my site, so that people viewing the artwork can easily share it on Facebook. The share button works in that the FB link does take the user to the correct artwork (url is correct). However, the image in the link is always an ugly clip out of the center of my logo banner (same image on every page on the site) and the og:xxx meta tags on my page seem to have absolutely no effect in customizing the link as Facebook claims they should. Here's the head section of one of my pages:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="https://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:og="https://ogp.me/ns#"     xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stitzart.css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1.0" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="keywords" content="art, acrylic, flip, pour, artwork, colorful, dirty cup" />
<meta name="description" content="Hilda Stitz Art Gallery featuring dirty cup pours in acrylic." />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.stitzweb.com/art/art.php?id=18" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="StitzArt - #033" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Little Planet" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.stitzweb.com/art/images/share018.png" />
<title>StitzArt - Hilda Stitz Artwork</title>
</head>
```

and the share button on that page pulls up this dialog:
[Facebook Share Dialog (with incorrect information)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8OSH.png)

How can I make the pic, title and description in the share dialog match what's in the meta data? I've searched all day and I've almost given up. The feature works for sharing, but it would be so much better if people could see a preview of the artwork before clicking on the link. Thanks in advance for any help you might offer.

Comment: IIRC Facebook is caching the metadata and you will have to flush the cache to get it updated. Have you checked https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ for details?

Comment: the meta keywords is no longer used.

Comment: Turns out Aaaron nailed it on the head, it had been three days since the first share at which time Facebook's bot "scraped" the site and gathered the info...then cached it. I simply had to "rescrape" it and now it works great. Thanks for the help! Oh, and thanks for the keywords info, I'll remove that tag.